Is there any query to find the value of column2 for value of column1 in bigQuery? column1 and column2 have related values
I have a table 'table1' with two columns 'Old_id' and 'new_id'. I want to populate another table extracting records from the table1. But table1 have values as below:



old_id
new_id




a1
b1


a2
b2


b1
c1


c1
d1


b2
c2


d1
e1



so to populate table2, for 'a1' final new_id should be 'e1'. if we trace the table1, we can see relation a1->b1 then b1->c1 then c1->d1 then d1->e1 and so on until we find the latest new id. similarly for 'a2' we have new_id 'b2' and then 'b2' also have new_id 'c2'. so the final new_id for 'a2' is 'c2. so the new table will have data as below



old_id
new_id




a1
e1


a2
c2



so can anyone suggest me a query compatible with BigQuery(GCP) to populate table2?
I was trying to populate table one 'new_id' column using different query that could possibly give new_id for old_id.

Are id values unique (in columns)? Do you know the upper limit of the number of steps/transitions? Is this number reasonably low (i.e. 5 or 10) or unlimited?

No, they are not unique, both column have multi to multi relation. And I don't know the upper limit of the transitions, the table get refreshed everyday. so the no could be unlimited. That's why i want to clean the data and store it in a new table.

You need recursive CTEs:
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/recursive-ctes

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

you can do this with recursion.
with recursive tbl as (
  select *, 1 pos  from <your_table>
  where old_id not in (select v from aw-dev-dswork-sdp-b311.gaurang.test_rec) 
  union all
  select t1.old_id, t2.new_id, pos + 1
  from tbl t1 
  join <your_table> t2
  on t2.old_id = t1.new_id
)

select old_id, new_id from (
select old_id, new_id, rank() over(partition by k order by(v) desc ) as rnk  from tbl
) where rnk = 1

